# Extending $.fn.init function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to extend jQuery with the following:

```
$.fn.extend({
    initCore:   $.fn.init,
    init:       function (selector, context, rootjQuery) {
        return $.fn.initCore(selector, context, rootjQuery);
    }
}),
```

However, it doesn't seem to work right, and creating simple things such as an alert on click produce errors. Can anyone spot the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$.fn.init` is the class constructor itself.

Try adding `$.fn.init.prototype = $.fn` afterwords to restore the original prototype.

Comment: Yes, but even then you can't use `return $.fn.initCore(...)`

Comment: It seems to work. I've prototyped the fn object though, so initCore will always be there to run, and I'm passing through the original parameters. Surely that's all that is needed?

Comment: Oh sorry, I see what you mean. I already changed $.fn to this.fn for it to work!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're missing the context. Try

```
return $.fn.initCore.call(this, selector, context, rootjQuery);
```

or even easier

```
return this.initCore(selector, context, rootjQuery);
```

---

No, wait, `init` is the constructor itself. That means

```
$.fn.initCore.call(this, selector, context, rootjQuery);
doSomeThingWith(this);

...

$.fn.init.prototype = $.fn;
```

or

```
var ob = new $.fn.initCore(selector, context, rootjQuery);
doSomeThingWith(ob);
return ob;
```

Comment: I fixed it by just putting $.fn.init.prototype = $.fn :) Thanks!

Comment: I don't think that's all. You are still calling `$.fn.initCore` with no context, which will lead to awfull errors.