# Difference of the value, prototype and property

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, reverse-engineering

OK! First of all this question comes from a man who digs too deep (and posibly get lost) in the jQuery universe.

In my reserch I discovered the jquery's main pattern is something like this (If needed correction is wellcomed):

```
(function (window, undefined) {

   jQuery = function (arg) {
      // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
      return new jQuery.fn.init(arg);
   },
   jQuery.fn = jQuery.prototype = {
      constructor: jQuery,
      init: function (selector, context, rootjQuery) {
         // get the selected DOM el.
         // and returns an array
      },
      method: function () {
         doSomeThing();
         return this;
      },
      method2: function () {
         doSomeThing();
         return this;,
         method3: function () {
            doSomeThing();
            return this;
         };

         jQuery.fn.init.prototype = jQuery.fn;

         jQuery.extend = jQuery.fn.extend = function () {

            //defines the extend method 
         };
         // extends the jQuery function and adds some static methods 
         jQuery.extend({
            method: function () {}

         })

      })
```

When `$` initiates the `jQuery.prototype.init` initiates and returns an array of elements. But i could not understand how it adds the jQuery method like `.css` or `.hide` ,etc. to this array.

I get the static methods. But could not get how it returns and array of elements with all those methods.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't like that pattern either. They have an `init` function, which is the constructor of all jQuery instances - the `jQuery` function itself is just a wrapper around that object creation with `new`:

```
function jQuery(…) { return new init(…); }
```

Then, they add the methods of those instances to the `init.prototype` object. This object is exposed as an interface at `jQuery.fn`. Also, they set the `prototype` property of the jQuery function to that object - for those who don't use the `fn` property. Now you have

```
jQuery.prototype = jQuery.fn = […]init.prototype
```

But they also do two [weird] things:

- overwriting the `constructor` property of the prototype object, setting it to the `jQuery` function
- exposing the `init` function on `jQuery.fn` - its own prototype. This might allow [Extending $.fn.init function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11146580/1048572), but is very confusing

I think they need/want to do all this to be fool-proof, but their code is a mess - starting with that object literal and assigning the init prototype things afterwards.

Comment: Is over-writing the constructor how they get `this`, i.e. the value returned to point to jQuery?...no this is what the #2 weird thing is for...what is #1 weird thing for?

Comment: this is essentially a hack for getting inits `this` to look like a jQuery `this`

Comment: No, the `constructor` *property* on the prototype object has nothing to do with the functionality. And I don't know what you mean when prattling "*getting inits `this` to look like a jQuery `this`*" - its just the usual "class" pattern

Comment: Don’t forget the endless prototype loop, f.ex: `new $.fn.init.prototype.init.prototype.init.prototype.init('body');`

Comment: Sure, altough you have such backreferences also with `…prototype.constructor.…`

Answer (score 3):

It’s easier to digest if you think of the API as an external collection of methods, and the jQuery function as the wrapper.

It’s basically constructed like this:

```
function a() { return new b();}
a.prototype.method = function() { return this; }
function b() {}
b.prototype = a.prototype;
```

Except that `a` is `jQuery` and `b` is `jQuery.prototype.init`.

I’m sure Resig had his reasons for placing the api constructor in the init prototype, but I can’t see them. A couple of more strangeness besides the ones Bergi mentioned:

1) The patterns requires a reference copy from `jQuery.fn.init.prototype` to `jQuery.prototype`, wich allows a weird endless loop:

```
var $body = new $.fn.init.prototype.init.prototype.init.prototype.init('body');
```

2) Every jQuery collection is actually an instance of `jQuery.fn.init`, but since they reference the same prototype object, it tricks us to "think" that the collection is an instance of `jQuery`. You can do the same sorcery like this:

```
function a(){}
function b(){}
a.prototype = b.prototype;
console.log( new b instanceof a); // true
console.log( new a instanceof b); // true
```

**Sidenote:** I have personally used the following constructor pattern with similar results without the weirdness:

```
var a = function(arg) {
    if (!(this instanceof a)) {
        return new a(arg);
    }
};
a.prototype.method = function(){ return this; };
```