# Calling new on a prototyped function | What does `this` refer to? | How to test?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What does this point to in this fiddle?

This copies the core parts of jQuery into a simple fiddle.

How can I test for what this points to?

http://jsfiddle.net/tFhFD/3/

**Reference**

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js

Comment: No, this is absolutely not the *core parts of jQuery*. If you're interested in those, read and understand [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12143590/1048572)

Comment: Holy fire ....that is some crazy stuff...overwriting the constructor!!

Comment: Is this how they get `this` to point to `jQuery`?

Comment: `this` does never point to `jQuery` (assuming a normal invocation)?

Comment: the init prototype points to the jQuery prototype..., the init constructor points to the jQuery constructor....hmmmm

Comment: technically it does not...but effectively it does...biggest hack I have seen to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [this introduction into the `this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this). You don't really know what `this` points to, it depends on the invocation of the function.

However, as the `init` function is invoked with the [`new` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new), `this` will be a new object that inherits from the `init.prototype` object - an *instance* of the init constructor function.

To inspect the value of `this`, use your debugger. You can also `console.log(this)`.

Comment: No, properties on `$` are not jQuery's prototype!

Comment: in what case is `constructor` used?

Comment: Usually never :-) It is a convenience property which instances inherit from the prototype object, and it points to their ... constructor function!

Comment: so by convenience you mean it doesn't do anything ?  Why do they set it to jQuery?

Comment: It is not used by any native functionality, but there may be custom functions that rely on it to clone instances etc

Comment: you mean other user-created functions might reference it for some reason or another ( cloning, etc. )?

Answer (score 1):

```
var $A = function (test) {
    return new $A.prototype.init(test);
};
$A.prototype = {
    init: function (test) {
        var a = 'function_var';
        this[0] = a;
        this[1] = arguments[0];
    }
};
document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML = $A('hi_there')[0];
console.debug(jQuery('hi_there'));
```

`this` in "this" case points to the instance of the `init` function.

Calling `$A`'s constructor function returns a `new` instance of `$A`'s prototype init function.

Comment: but then jQuery would not work...this is copied directly from jQuery code.

Comment: sorry check out the source http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js....I mean in their code they use this form...

Comment: When you use the `new` keyword with a function, the function will be called with the `this` pointer pointing to a *new* freshly created object.

Comment: I know my point is that when you use `$()` it points to `jQuery.prototype.init`...which would do nothing except return the dom selection you would not be able to call methods.

Comment: my answer is very accurate. calling new on a `function` creates a `new` instance of said function, in this case `init`. what's inaccurate?

Comment: @Xander In your answer you don't explicitly mention the necessity of using the `new` keyword. Also, maybe it's just the way I think, but I just see constructors as code acting on new objects.