# jQuery prototype

Tags: javascript, jquery

According to this StackOverflow answer [What does jQuery.fn mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083351/what-does-jquery-fn-mean), the fn property in `jQuery.fn.jquery` is an alias to the prototype property. I assume that this would be the same in these two methods whose full code is below

`$.fn.map = function()`  and `$.fn.tweets = function()`

My question then, is, if, for example,  $.fn.tweets uses the prototype to create a tweets method, would this code with `$('tweets').tweets`  be calling it...

```
var $tweets = $('#tweets').tweets({
        query: buildQuery(approxLocation),
        template: '#tweet-template'
    });
```

and, if so, how might it trigger that method. **For example, does the mere creation of the variable on file loading trigger that function,** which has other methods inside of it, namely query?  Thanks for your help

Full code of methods

```
  $.fn.map = function(method) {
         console.trace();
         console.log(method);
        if (method == 'getInstance') {
            console.log("fn.map");
            return this.data('map');
        }

        return this.each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            var map = $this.data('map');

            if (map && MyMap.prototype[method]) {
                 map[method] (Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
            } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
                var options = method;
                $this.data('map', new MyMap( this, options ));
            } else {
                $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.map' );
            }
        });
    }

   $.fn.tweets = function(method) {

        if ( methods[method] ) {
            return methods[ method ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
        } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {

            return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
        } else {
            $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.tweets' );
        }
    }
```

**variables that call those methods?**

```
 var $tweets = $('#tweets').tweets({
        query: buildQuery(approxLocation),
        template: '#tweet-template'
    });
var $map = $('#map').map({
    initialLocation: approxLocation,
    radius: 1000,
    locationChanged: function(location) {
        $tweets.tweets('setQuery', buildQuery(location));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Firstly, prototypes are just objects. In this case, yes:

```
jQuery.prototype === jQuery.fn
```

So saying `jQuery.fn.map = function() {}` is like saying `jQuery.prototype.map = function() {}`

When you **instantiate a new jquery object** with `$(selector | dom node | ...)` you are returning a `jQuery` object which automatically inherits all the prototype methods, including map, tweet, etc. Research Javascript's prototypal inheritence model and how object prototypes work in regard to `new`

`$` is just a reference to `jQuery` which returns a specially modified **new object**. `$` is a **function** which returns a new object reference. Here's a simplified example (but you really should research more about prototypal inheritence, it has been answered many times repeatedly):

```
var A = function() {
};

A.prototype.doThing = function() {
};

var newObj = new A();

newObj.doThing // this new object has this method because it's on A's prototype
```

so `newObj.doThing` is just like `$(selector).tweet`

Also feel free to [read the source](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js) of jQuery and trace what happens when a new object is created. You can see near the top exactly what is happening under the comment `// Define a local copy of jQuery`

Comment: thanks, so does the creation of this variable upon file loading trigger that prototype method? In the code I provided, it doesn't use the 'new' constructor.  var $tweets = $('#tweets').tweets({

Comment: @user1647484: Yet, right inside the `$` function, an instance of the actual jQuery constructor is created via `new` and returned. Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12143833/1048572) for the internals