# Javascript Library Extend way

Tags: javascript, object, extend

I'm writing my own JavaScript library. How can I do for extend my object in this way?

```
_.mymethod();
```

Here's my code:

```
(function (window, undefined) {
    "use strict";

    var emptyArray = [];

    function _(id) {
        return new _.fd.init(id);
    }

    _.fd = _.prototype = {
        init: function (selector) {
            this.el = document.getElementById(sel);
            return this;
        },
        replaceText: function (text) {
            this.el.innerHTML = text;
            return this;
        },
        changeTextColor: function (color) {
            this.el.style.color = color;
            return this;
        }
    };

    _.fd.init.prototype = _.fd;
    _.extend = function (target) {};
    _.extend({});

    window._ = _;
}(window));
```

The point is, how to extend for using method like

```
_.method();
```

Comment: What is your question :) ?

Comment: Do you want to create new methods like `replaceText`? If so, just add them to `_.fd`.

Comment: What's the point of defining the property `fd` on `_` and `init` on `_.prototype`?

Comment: I need to have _.mymethod() ..

Comment: Do not follow the [jQuery pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12143590/1048572).

Comment: _.prototype.method = function () {..... };