# Which form of initialization is better?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I first started writing my own code I never understand jQuery's 'enhanced' init constructor until later on so I stuck to a different way of constructing my objects. I was wondering if I should keep my old ways or start using my own 'enhanced' init constructor.

---

My Constructor:

```
var $ = function(selector,context,createObj) {
        if(createObj) {
           // actually initiating object
        } else {
           return new $(selector,context,true);
        }
};
```

---

jQuery:

```
jQuery = function( selector, context ) {
    // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
    return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );
};
```

Actual Init:

```
init: function( selector, context, rootjQuery ) {
    // some code
}
```

Changing prototype (jQuery.prototype.init.prototype=jQuery.prototype):

```
jQuery.fn.init.prototype = jQuery.fn;
```

Comment: It would be cool if you could show the alternative as well.

Comment: Added jQuery's constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[jQuery's constructor pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12143590/1048572) is historically grown and bad practise - or at least unnecessarily complicated. If you want a constructor that works well without `new` (if applied wrong), use

```
function $(selector, context) {
    if (this instanceof $) {
        // actually initiating object
    } else {
        return new $(selector, context);
    }
}
```

Comment: So with analogy to **[my code]**(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23184344/javascripts-super-constructor-clarification) - you will start add methods at line #3 in your code ? `if (this instanceof $) { this.foo=function (){...}...}` ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Or you do an early return and just prepend your usual constructor by `if (!(this instanceof $)) return new $(…);`