# what's the return value of `$(undefined)` in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

The return value of `$(undefined)` is an object or array or what?

The the body of `$`:

```
  return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );
```

The particle body of `jQuery.fn.init` is:

```
  // HANDLE: $(""), $(null), $(undefined), $(false)
  if ( !selector ) {
          return this;
  }
```

My understanding is that:

```
 return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );
            ~~~~~~~~~~
                ^
                |
               this?
```

Answer (score 3):

No. It's used with the [`new` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new), so the `jQuery.fn.` doesn't matter. What matters is its `.prototype`, which is `jQuery.fn`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12143590/1048572) for the details.

> So what's the return value of `$(undefined)`?

It's an empty object inheriting from jQuery's prototype, so it's the same as `Object.create($.fn)`.

Answer (score 0):

The result is a jQuery object which does not contain any matched DOM elements; i.e. an "empty" jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

`$(undefined)` will return a jQuery instance with `""` selector.

Try it yourself with this code:

```
var output = '';
var jq = $(undefined);

for(var x in jq) {
    output += x + ' => "' + jq[x].toString() + '"' + "\n";
}

alert(output);
```

---

Sample output will be somewhat like this: http://pastebin.com/MwKYFM5w

Comment: No, the empty string is not really a selector - it would be handled like `undefined` :-)

Comment: So will `$(undefined)` truncate `undefined` into `""` ?

Comment: They will both just be treated as "no selector" - the result is not even an empty collection (with `length` 0, `context` and `selector` properties) but an empty object without any properties.