# __proto__ vs. prototype inheritance in javascript

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

First of all, this question is really similar to several others on this site. I have read them, but still have questions

These two helped, but didn't get me all the way:

- [How does **proto** differ from constructor.prototype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650764/how-does-proto-differ-from-constructor-prototype)
- [_proto__ VS. prototype in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959727/proto-vs-prototype-in-javascript)

I have this basic setup of a javascript framework/library:

```
(function(global){

    var TMath = function() {
        return new TMath.init();
    }

    TMath.prototype = {
        add: function(a, b) {
            return a+b;
        }
    };

    TMath.init = function(){};

    TMath.init.prototype = TMath.prototype;

    global.TMath = global.$$ = TMath;

})(window);
```

When I run it like so:

```
var test = $$()

console.log(test);
```

I see the following in my console:

[image]

What I don't understand is:

If I `console.log` out `test.__proto__`, I get `Object{}`.

Shouldn't I get `TMath.Init.prototype`, since that's the `function constructor` my `test` instance was created with?

Here is an example where this does happen:

```
function Person(name){
    this.dob = dob
 }; 

var person = new Person("name");

console.log(person.__proto__);
```

This outputs `Person{}`, and **not** `Object{}`

Comment: `var test = $$()` => `var test = TMath();` you then get a new object from `new TMath.init();`, its prototype is `TMath.prototype`, so `test.__proto__` is `TMath.prototype`,  which is the `object` with an `add` method, what's wrong with that?

Comment: Avoid the [jQuery antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12143590/difference-of-the-value-prototype-and-property/12143833#12143833) :-)

Comment: Um, `TMath.Init.prototype` *is* `Object{}`? Also it is `=== TMath.prototype;`, so how should the console know which name to display? **Names mean nothing.** Especially when you are looking for object identities.

Comment: These are the same thing, the console is just giving it a generic name, `$$().__proto__ === $$.prototype; // true`

Comment: @Bergi ok - cool. The naming stuff tripped me up a bit :)

Answer (score 2):

Let's walk through your code piece by piece and see what we end up with.

In the following image(s), this is the nomenclature:

- Elipse = function
- Rectangle = object
- Arrow = property

  - **p** = `.prototype`
  - **c** = `.constructor`
  - **P** = `.__proto__` or `[[Prototype]]`
- All anonymous items are empty shapes and all named items contain the name

---

#### 1) Create a function `TMath`

When a function is created, JS engine also creates an *anonymous* object and binds the two using `.prototype` and `.constructor` properties as follows:

```
function foo(){}

/* performed by JS engine */
// foo.prototype = {};
// foo.prototype.constructor = foo;
```

```
var TMath = function() {
    return new TMath.init();
}
```

[image]

---

#### 2) Replace a function's `prototype` with another object

We are re-assigning the link `TMath.prototype`, so that it now points to the new object.

This new object also has an anonymous function in it, referenced by `.add()`.
And the said function comes with its own default `.prototype` object.

```
TMath.prototype = {
    add: function(a, b) {
        return a+b;
    }
};
```

[image]

---

#### 3) Add a property to an object or a function

This one is simple.
Just add a new link to the object/function to which the new property is added.

In our case, the link is `.init()` and the property is an anonymous function.

```
TMath.init = function(){};
```

[image]

---

#### 4) Replace a function's `prototype` with another object

Just like step 2, we re-assign the link `TMath.prototype`.
But rather than creating a new object, we point it to an existing object.

```
TMath.init.prototype = TMath.prototype;
```

[image]

---

#### Let's clear up the drawings a bit.

[image]

---

#### 5) instantiation

Still with me?

Good! Becaue this is where the *magic* happens.

When you do `var test = $$()`, you are actually doing `var test = TMath()`, which is just `var test = new TMath.init()`

We can even say that this is the **exact same** as

`var test = new <function referenced by TMath.init>()`.

When using `new` while invoking the function, the following rule applies:

> If `new` is used in assignment, the returned object is provided with the property `.__proto__`
>   
>   (or `[[Prototype]]`), which is a reference to the object referenced by
>   
>   constructor-function's `.prototype`

Therefore, the created object (in this case `test`) has a property `__proto__` that points to the `TMath.init.prototype`.

[image]

And you can confirm all this by doing the following:

```
console.log(test.__proto__ === TMath.init.prototype) // true
console.log(test.__proto__ === TMath.prototype) // true
```

---

#### Conclusion

Indeed what you originally thought is correct

> If I `console.log` out `test.\_\_proto\_\_`, I get `Object{}`.
>
> Shouldn't I get `TMath.Init.prototype`, since that's the function constructor my `test` instance was created with?

To gain command over these core concepts of JS, I **highly** recommend reading http://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-prototype/