# Setting function constructor prototype (in example)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand an example from a course *"JavaScript: Understanding the Weird Parts"*. There is line of code `Greeter.init.prototype = Greeter.prototype;` that is used to make `Greeter.prototype` to be the prototype of all objects created from `Greeter.init` function constructor, so we can set the methods in `Greeter.prototype`.

But i can't figure out why to not set the methods directly in `Greeter.init.prototype`. It will work the same. The line `Greeter.init.prototype = Greeter.prototype;` looks like redundant code. What is advantage of original approach?

Original code:

```js
(function(global, $) {
    
  var Greetr = function(firstName, lastName, language) {
      return new Greetr.init(firstName, lastName, language);   
  }

  Greetr.prototype = {
    fullName: function() {
      return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
    }
  };

  Greetr.init = function(firstName, lastName, language) {      
    var self = this;
    self.firstName = firstName || '';
    self.lastName = lastName || '';
    self.language = language || 'en';       
  }

  Greetr.init.prototype = Greetr.prototype;

  global.Greetr = global.G$ = Greetr;
    
}(window, jQuery));


var g = G$('John', 'Doe');
console.log(g);
console.log(g.fullName());
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Simplified code:

```js
(function(global, $) {
    
  var Greetr = function(firstName, lastName, language) {
      return new Greetr.init(firstName, lastName, language);   
  }

  Greetr.init = function(firstName, lastName, language) {      
    var self = this;
    self.firstName = firstName || '';
    self.lastName = lastName || '';
    self.language = language || 'en';       
  }

  Greetr.init.prototype = {
    fullName: function() {
      return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
    }
  };

  global.Greetr = global.G$ = Greetr;
    
}(window, jQuery));


var g = G$('John', 'Doe');
console.log(g);
console.log(g.fullName());
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: [Don't use this pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12143833/1048572), it's pretty outdated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the `Greetr` constructor calls the `Greetr.init` constructor, and overrides its return value by explicitly returning an object, there's no difference between them.

The two codes create exactly the same object structure and work the same, with one difference: the second one leaves `Greetr.prototype` in its initial state.

However, most likely, the original code made `Greetr.prototype` and `Greetr.init.prototype` to the same object, because this way it's possible to access and/or extend it without typing `.init`, which is more semantical: you intend to change the prototype of objects created by `Greetr`, whose prototype is normally `Greetr.prototype`. Also, in the first code, `instanceof` will consider objects created by `Greetr` and `Greetr.init` as the instances of `Greetr`. So:

```js
(function(global, $) {
    
  var Greetr = function(firstName, lastName, language) {
      return new Greetr.init(firstName, lastName, language);   
  }

  Greetr.prototype = {
    fullName: function() {
      return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
    }
  };

  Greetr.init = function(firstName, lastName, language) {      
    var self = this;
    self.firstName = firstName || '';
    self.lastName = lastName || '';
    self.language = language || 'en';       
  }

  Greetr.init.prototype = Greetr.prototype;

  global.Greetr = global.G$ = Greetr;
    
}(window, jQuery));


var g = G$('John', 'Doe');
console.log(g instanceof G$);
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

```js
(function(global, $) {
    
  var Greetr = function(firstName, lastName, language) {
      return new Greetr.init(firstName, lastName, language);   
  }

  Greetr.init = function(firstName, lastName, language) {      
    var self = this;
    self.firstName = firstName || '';
    self.lastName = lastName || '';
    self.language = language || 'en';       
  }

  Greetr.init.prototype = {
    fullName: function() {
      return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
    }
  };

  global.Greetr = global.G$ = Greetr;
    
}(window, jQuery));


var g = G$('John', 'Doe');
console.log(g instanceof G$);
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```