# Why is the init function in jQuery.prototype and not in jQuery's closure?

Tags: jquery

Why is the init function in jQuery.prototype? I have put it in jQuery's closure and it works fine. I did this:

```
(function( window, undefined ) {

    var jQuery = function( selector, context ) {
        return new init( selector, context, rootjQuery );
    }
    var init=function( selector, context, rootjQuery ) {
        ...
    }
    ...
})(...)
```

Thanks,

Eric J.

Answer (score 3):

We don't know (ask the library maintainers for their design desicions).

But having it available as a public property does allow [overwriting or amending the constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11146580/extending-fn-init-function) without harming the `jQuery` function, and it makes [prototypical inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10898786/correct-javascript-inheritance) possible where you might need to apply the parent constructor on the child instance:

```
function MyJQuery(selector, context) {
    this.init(selector, context, MyJQuery.root); // <==
    // or more explicit:
    // jQuery.fn.init.call(this, selector, …);
    …
}
MyJQuery.fn = MyJQuery.prototype = Object.create(jQuery.fn);
MyJQuery.root = jQuery(document);
```

Comment: Awesome, makes sense that the authors would do this since it sort of follows the `init` naming convention of [Resig's inheritance pattern](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/).

Comment: Exactly, only that Resig's pattern does not follow the JavaScript naming conventions which expect the initialisation method on the `.constructor` property :-)