# Passing jQuery function to higher-order function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm experimenting with higher-order functions in Javascript and I wrote up something like this:

```
function hof (setter) {
    setter("not test");
}

function hof2 (setter) {
    setter.call(window.jQuery, "not test 2");
}

var span = $("#myTest").text;
hof(span);
hof2(span);
```

Here's the jsFiddle version: http://jsfiddle.net/6mcYt/

However, both functions throw an error. What is the best way to pass jQuery setter functions to a higher-order function?

Comment: The following answer might interest you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18907888/how-to-wrap-the-jquery-function/18908560#18908560

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want to do (I am not 100% sure) should be like this.

```
function hof ($el) {
    $.fn.text.call($el, 'test1')
}

var span = $("#myTest");
hof(span);
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6mcYt/2/

Another option is to bind the text method with context first.

```
function hof2 (setter) {
    setter("not test 2");
}
var spanFn = $.proxy($.fn.text, $("#myTest"));
hof2(spanFn);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6mcYt/3/)

Comment: What's the point, you could just do `return $el.text('test1')` inside `hof`.

Comment: yeah this is pointless. The second method is closer to the OP's question.

Comment: Second method is exactly what I was looking for, as hof2 still has no idea as to what kind of function it's being passed (i.e. could be jQuery or not).

Answer (score 3):

The `text` function actually belongs on `jQuery.fn` (which is also assigned to the prototype property of the jQuery constructor). If you pass that as the first argument to `setter.call`, it will stop throwing an error. BUT it won't work if the desired result is changing the text on `#myTest`, because you won't have any reference to the element anymore (you left that on `$("#myTest")`, which is an *instance* of the jQuery constructor).

Sorry if I can't offer an actual solution, I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: +1 - I agree. There is no context for the myTest jQuery object when the pointer to the prototype function is passed.